# Firefox addons in java

Tags: java, firefox-addon

Is it possible to write firefox add-ons in java? I'm trying to write an addon to load links on the current web page in the background with the goal of speeding up web browsing.

I know firefox addons use XUL for the user interface and JavaScript for the programming end. I'm just wondering if the programming can be done in java instead

Comment: You could write the add-on in Java and compile it to JavaScript using GWT.

Comment: I don't think @yshavit is correct. Addon javascript is a specific form of javascript for firefox. So the answer would be, no you cant, you have to do it in js. I think.

Comment: @Noitidart What do you mean a specific form? Is it a different dialect, or just use different libraries? I'm not sure how/if GWT deals with external js libraries (like, is there a way of asserting "these method calls exist, don't worry yourself about the fact that you can't find them"?).

Comment: @yshavit its regular javascript with access to C++ components, so it's very heavy on Cc Ci Cu etc. And then the js-ctypes portion is js and obeys js syntax, like objects and stuff, but its different, i dont think a regular js converter could handle it unless its targeting firefox privelaged scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported way to write Firefox addons in Java.